# How to randomly select from arrayLists and add to an object?

Tags: java, math, arraylist

"Implement
the
MenuRandomize
class.
The
constructor
receives
the
file
name
of
4
files,
one
for
each
type
of
meal,
and
uses
FileManager
to
load
data
from
these
text
files
into
the
4
ArrayList
decleared
as
properties
(one
array
for
each
type
of
dish)."

Right now I am stuck on the randomMenu(). How do I randomly select from arrayLists and add to an object? I think I should return Menu but it returns an error. I have selected a random number. Do I take that index from another arrayList (that element) and store it in a different arrayList ? I have this so far.

```
public class MenuRandomize {

private ArrayList<Entree> entree;
private ArrayList<Salad> salad;
private ArrayList<Dessert> dessert;
private ArrayList<Side> side;

public MenuRandomize(String entreeFile, String sideFile, String saladFile, String dessertFile) {
    entree = FileManager.readEntrees(entreeFile);
    dessert = FileManager.readDesserts(dessertFile);
    side= FileManager.readSides(sideFile);
    salad= FileManager.readSalads(saladFile);
}

public randomMenu() {
    ArrayList<Menu> menu;
    int indexEntrees=(int) Math.random() * entree.size() - 1;
    entree = entrees.get(indexEntrees);

    int indexD=(int) Math.random() * dessert.size() - 1;
    dessert = desserts.get(indexD);
                             **<----add element here to arrayList <Menu>?**
    int indexSalad=(int) Math.random() * salad.size() - 1;
    salad = salads.get(indexSalad);

    int indexSide=(int) Math.random() * side.size() - 1;
    entree = sides.get(indexSide);

    return null; **<--- return Menu?**
```

---

Is this better?

```
public randomMenu() {
    ArrayList<Menu> menu;
    //= new ArrayList <Menu>();
    int indexEntrees=(int) Math.random() * entree.size() - 1;
    entree = entrees.get(indexEntrees);
        Menu.add(0,entree);
    int indexD=(int) Math.random() * dessert.size() - 1;
    dessert = desserts.get(indexD);
    Menu.add(1,dessert);
    int indexSalad=(int) Math.random() * salad.size() - 1;
    salad = salads.get(indexSalad);
    Menu.add(2,dessert);
    int indexSide=(int) Math.random() * side.size() - 1;
    entree = sides.get(indexSide);
    Menu.add(3,dessert);
    return Menu[];
```

Comment: I suggest use an IDE. You are defining list as `menu` and using `Menu` to call add on it. Java is a case sensitive language. And you cannot just return anything without specifying return type. Please refer my answer for some points.

Comment: I see no reason to have separate classes Entree, Salad, Dessert, and Side. Those can all be in one class, Food. The variable menu should be an ArrayList<Food>. You need to add to the ArrayList menu, not the class Menu. At the end of randomMenu() you should return menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of errors in your code. It will not even compile. Try to use an IDE.

1. Change return type of `randomMenu()` method to `ArrayList<Menu>` if you want to return it.
2. You cannot do `entree = entrees.get(indexEntrees);` calling get in the list will get you single instance of `Entree` but your `entree` is a List.  Same thing you have done with others. Also You have used Entree reference for Side instance.
3. You are not actually adding into the menu list. Also for this to work All your Deseret, Side etc classes should extend Menu class.

Your code should be like -

```
public ArrayList<Menu> randomMenu() {
    ArrayList<Menu> menu = new ArrayList<Menu>();
    int indexEntrees=(int) Math.random() * entree.size() - 1;
    Entree randomEntree = entrees.get(indexEntrees);
    menu.add(randomEntree);

    int indexD=(int) Math.random() * dessert.size() - 1;
    Dessert randomDessert = desserts.get(indexD);
    menu.add(randomDessert);

    int indexSalad=(int) Math.random() * salad.size() - 1;
    Salad randomSalad = salads.get(indexSalad);
    menu.add(randomSalad);

    int indexSide=(int) Math.random() * side.size() - 1;
    Side randomSide = side.get(indexSide);
    menu.add(randomSide);

    return menu;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does add always result in a syntax error?

Comment: Because your Classes like Desert, Side, Entree do not extend Menu class.

Comment: As I said make your food classes extend Menu class. For Eg.
`public class Dessert extends Menu{}`

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to make Dessert extend Menu. Dessert might extend Food.

Comment: @DouglasZare edited the error typo. You are right it does not make sense to use Menu as the super class. I answered to what OP had already code for. By Logical naming convention it should be `ArrayList<FoodItem> menu = new ArrayList<FoodItem>();` where FoodItem is a class or interface that other concrete FoodItems actually extend or implement.